# Подзапрос в процедуре

Tags: sql, база-данных, plsql, plsql-developer

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь скомпилить пакет процедур в plsql developer, ругается на подзапрос в процедуре, погуглив, узнал, что такие вещи не поддерживаются девелопером. К сожалению, моих знаний не хватает найти решение, которое заменит этот подзапрос, могу расчитывать на помощь с поиском варианта?
Сама строчка кода на которую ругается

```
begin  
-- проверка, числится ли эталон в перечне неработоспособных 
  if p_StandartId in (select n.standart_id from metrology.non_workable_standarts n) then
```

Comment: заводим локальную переменную. затем делаем в нее SELECT CASE p_StandartId in (select ...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END INTO local_variable FROM dual; ну и потом уже IF local_variable = 1 THEN

Answer (score 1):

Заводим переменную, выбираем в нее количество записей, подошедших под условие. В условии используем это количество.

```
declare
 non_working number;
begin
 select count(*)
   into non_working
   from metrology.non_workable_standarts
  where standart_id=p_StandartId;

 if non_working > 0 then ...
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Не имел опыта с plsql, но рискну предположить, что можно сделать `OUTER JOIN` по полям p_StandartId и standart_id и отобрать те записи, где `standart_id IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
begin  
for rec in (select * 
            from metrology.non_workable_standarts n
            where n.standart_id = p_StandartId )
loop
  --делаем здесь то что хотели делать по if then, пользуясь rec.имя поля
end loop;
end;
```